# Automatically cancel build on first error in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for a way to make visual studio cancel the build immediately after the first C++ compile error.

There's an [extension called "StopOnFirstBuildError"](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91aaa139-5d3c-43a7-b39f-369196a84fa5), but - contrary to its name - it stops the build only after the first project has failed (so if I happen to have just one project in my solution, it does exactly nothing). There are some macros out there that claim to do that, but macro support was dropped in VS2012, so I can't use them since I'm using visual studio 2013.

What I do manually and why: Whenever the first time the word "error" appears in the output, I choose "Build -> Cancel" (ctrl-break) and VS stops building immediately. The reason: often, the first error is the only "real" one and once it is fixed, many of the subsequent ones disappear (e.g. in case of syntax errors). Since every error report after the first one is basically worthless to me - and even if not, I have to fix them all anyway and might as well do it from top to bottom - I'd rather not have to scroll upwards through the subsequent errors that appeared in the output because I was too slow to press ctrl-break. The unnecessary activity in the output window is visually distracting as well. Another reason I cancel the build is that sometimes I finish fixing the first error while the build is still running and I have to cancel it to try building again. This happens hundreds of times in given coding day and the constant interference with my workflow is annoying.

So: Is there a way to automatically invoke the "Build -> Cancel" command whenever a build error occurs?